# Cannot query field "repository" on type "Query"

Tags: node.js, graphql

I really need your help today.
Indeed, I'm currently discovering this cool tool named Graphql in order to recuperate some datas from Github, which are issues with specific labels in several github project. And the thing is there is no problem when I send my request online with Graphiql : 
 [image]

But problems arrive when I try to send the same request from a NodeJs server, and I don't really know why.
Here is the code that I wrote, where I use graphql-request to send my request :

```
const { request } = require("graphql-request");

const query = `query getIssues($nameOwner : String!, $labels : [String!], $repo1 : String!) {
  repo1 : repository(owner: $nameOwner, name: $repo1) {
    name
    url
    issues(labels:$labels, first:100, states:[OPEN]) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          url
          labels(first:3) {
            edges {
              node {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`;

const variables = {
  nameOwner: "inextensodigital",

  repo1: "emeabridge.eu",
  repo2: "deloittedirect.dk",
  repo3: "deloitteexperts.com",
  repo4: "easydeloitte.at",
  repo5: "inexweb.fr",
  repo6: "propelbydeloitte.com",

  repos: [
    "emeabridge.eu",
    "deloittedirect.dk",
    "deloitteexperts.com",
    "easydeloitte.at",
    "inexweb.fr",
    "propelbydeloitte.com"
  ],

  labels: [
    "ideas",
    "backlog",
    "priorisation",
    "definiton",
    "proposal",
    "acceptance",
    "in progress"
  ]
};

request("https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/movies", query, variables).then(
  data => console.log(data)
);
```

And here Is the error I get on my console after launching the NodeJs server : 
[image: console error]

Thanks in advance for your answers guys, and please understand that I'm currently learning Graphql, so I might do some terrible things in my code :) :)